# Should I use "either way" or "in any case" in the following case?

Tags: word-choice, either-any

> The only thing we had to worry about was whether she would receive us
> or slam the door in our faces. **In any case**, we had to go; we had to
> find out who killed Richard.
>
> The only thing we had to worry about was whether she would receive us
> or slam the door in our faces. **Either way**, we had to go; we had to
> find out who killed Richard.

What's the correct option here, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with one of the following:

> Either way, ...
>
> In **either** case, ...

You only have two options, so *either* is a better option because it implies two outcomes.  *Any* implies more than two options.